# Centroid, length and width of a rectangle in an image

Tags: matlab

I have an image as shown below:

[image]

I want find out the following properties of each of the rectangle inside the image
(i) centroid (ii) length (iii) width (iv) area (v) perimeter
using MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since they are all rectangles, you actually only need to find the bounding boxes. And you can find the boxes as:

```
img = imread('img.jpg');
bw = im2bw(img);

cc = bwconncomp(bw);
stats = regionprops(cc, 'BoundingBox');
```

Here is the result with your image in *stats.BoundingBox* is:

```
[36,50 37,50 29 29]
[46,50 363,50 11 13]
[60,50 135,50 10 8]
[60,50 246,50 7 14]
[155,50 42,50 8 14]
[155,50 156,50 3 3]
[155,50 260,50 5 8]
[182,50 355,50 5 8]
[259,50 48,50 7 8]
[261,50 260,50 3 2]
[261,50 366,50 5 8]
[280,50 154,50 8 8]
[365,50 151,50 8 8]
[367,50 13,50 8 8]
[373,50 262,50 2 3]
[394,50 358,50 5 8]
```

**--EDIT--**

To make things clear, [regionprops](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) can also calculate the perimeter, area and center of mass if you call with extra parameters such as `stats = regionprops(cc, 'BoundingBox', 'Centroid', 'Area', 'Perimeter');`. But, if the regions are always simple rectangles without rotation as in your case AND if there are too many images to process I would calculate them myself in favor of speed. Otherwise, just to keep things simple and/or safe, regionprops would be the way to go. As I mentioned in the comments below, with 10000 iterations it takes 9 seconds (manually) vs 40 seconds (regionprops) on my PC to calculate all of the metrics.

Comment: Yes, but since `regionprops` has properties for `'Centroid'`, `'Area'` and `'Perimeter'`, why not get them from the function call instead of manually calculating them?

Comment: @beaker if it's certain that all the regions are rectangular, it would be a waste of (cpu) time to use those functions (somehow i always try to consider resources :) ). I didn't provide them on purpose because it was so obvious in this case to calculate them.

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like premature optimization. Do you have any evidence that calculating these statistics outside the `regionprops` function is any more efficient that doing it inside the function? If so, at what point does this difference become significant? Certainly not at 16 components; perhaps 10,000? 1,000,000?

Comment: @beaker I've just got the evidence on my PC. I've tried calculating manually and by regionprops with the OP's case through 1, 100, 1000, 10000 times. Here are the results for regionprops: 0.040668, 0.427562, 3.651436, 38.497505. And the results for manual one: 0.005925, 0.140086, 0.976332, 9.232980. I accept that regionprops always produce the correct result. But in the OP's case, if I were to processing thousands of images, I would certainly go for manual calculation.

Comment: @beaker By the way I was sure that regionprops would be slower because it has to use all the pixels in each region one by one to calculate each of these metrics. On the other hand, if you are certain that they are rectangular, it's easy as a sum or multiplication operation!

Comment: `regionprops` definitely calculates the required properties but does it provide the correct positional centroid? Also I saw that when the number of rectangles increase say by 128x128=16384, `regionprops` does not return all the rectangle's properties rather it eliminates a few like in my case it returns <16357x1 struct> whereas it should have been <16384x1 struct>.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that if you use `regionprops` you can just as much get the centroid as well:

```
 stats = regionprops(cc, 'BoundingBox', 'centroid');
```